# Kalki Avatar ( Kali Yuga )

Tags: vishnu, kali-yuga, brahmins, kshatriya, kalki-purana

will in near future Democracy end in India and will Kshatriya's again rule Our country coz in Kalki Puran they have told that Shri Kalki will have 2 wives and both wives father will be king

King Vrihadrath and King Shashi dhwaja

Hence will Kshatriya's again rule in near future to come ?

Comment: In that case, I will be glad, because a strong and positive dictatorship can be way better than the current status of Indian democracy, Or you can say that these two kings can be the then Prime-minister, one of the chief ministers or president. So make sure if in the near future when someone stands for election having names Vrihadrath or Shashi dhwaja, Please vote for them. :) :D

Comment: It will take at least 300000 years before he comes so your worries are long gone before he comes.